Why do Instruction Pointers in eBPF stack trace contain the eBPF program twice with the same IP, and a weird unrelated IP?
When taking kernel stack traces in an eBPF program, I get duplicate and a seemingly weird entry: can someone please shed some light on this?
Let's start with the eBPF program fragments that are relevant; first, I've declared a stack trace map as follows:
struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_STACK_TRACE);
    __type(key, u32);
    __type(value, stack);
    __uint(max_entries, 1 << 14);
} stacks SEC(".maps");

In the eBPF program (that later gets attached to cap_capable), I store a stack trace as follows and then later send the stack trace ID into user space:
kstackid = bpf_get_stackid(ctx, &stacks, 0);

The user space side is in Go, using Cilium's incredibly helpful ebpf Go module. In order to read the instruction pointers of a particular stack back trace, I do as follows:
ips := make([]uint64, MaxStackDepth)
if err := objs.Stacks.Lookup(event.Kstackid, ips); err != nil {
    slog.Error("looking up kernel stack trace", "error", err)
    continue
}
l := len(ips)
for idx, ip := range ips {
    if ip == 0 {
        l = idx
        break
    }
}
ev := Event{
    bpfCapevent: event,
    KernelStack: ips[:l],
}

Now, when I resolve the instruction pointers using the data from /proc/kallsyms I end up with a stack looking like this, the IPs are additionally shown:
bpf_prog_47f71ae01d77a0b5_fentry_cap_capable ffffffffc00860ed
bpf_prog_47f71ae01d77a0b5_fentry_cap_capable ffffffffc00860ed
udp_tunnel_nic_init_module ffffffffc0e2004f
cap_capable ffffffff9ea9b1a5


Why are there two IPs for the fentry on cap_capable? They are both the same return addresses, so what is going on here?
What is the intermediate function between cap_capable and my eBPF program, udp_tunnel_nic_init_module looks like a mis-interpretation? Could it be related to trampolines...?

